# How to make the dropdown menu collapse when not in use

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a dropdown menu and when I click it it works but when I click out it stays open. I've tried using mouseout mousedown onclick ondblclick etc but none of them work. Please help :(

```
[What I've tried][1]
```

Comment: please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Sorry  Stack Overflow wasnt letting me. I've edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach `click` listener to your `document`, if clicked element is `img` then display dropwdown else hide.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#dropdown');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  menu.classList.toggle('show', e.target.tagName == "IMG");
});
```

```css
.menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 24px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  top: 73px;
  right: -24px;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #B00D93;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.skillcrush.com/skillcrush/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Screen-Shot-2018-06-13-at-8.07.34-PM.png" id="dropdownImg" alt="" width="45px" height="45px">
  <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About Us</a>
    <a href="">Services</a>
    <a href="">Feedback</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this : https://jsfiddle.net/85yz7asd/

```
showHide = () => {
 var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown") 
 dropdown.style.display == "block" ?  dropdown.style.display = "none" : dropdown.style.display = "block"
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So you make it a conditional to check if the showhide method returns true or false

Comment: @MarkOrji for cleaner implementation get rid of the `onblur` function, update your `show()` to `show = () => {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}` and add `.dropdown.show{
  display: block;
}` to your css. There are different ways to achieve this :)

Comment: @MarkOrji thanks , if you think the result helps please give it an upvote or validate it as an answer

Comment: @MarkOrji yep that will work too ... add an answer with that just replace jquery with pure js since the OP is using it

Answer (score 0):

This is a Pure **HTML** and **CSS** example:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-btn">Hover Me</div>
        <ul class="dropdown-list">
            <li><a href="">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link #3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-btn {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
        color: white;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-list {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-list li a {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: black;
        color: white;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown-list li a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
        color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-list {
    display: block;
}
```

[working js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bxgye1d/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your current code, try this.
Clicking on the `dropdownImg` element will open the menu.
Clicking anywhere else will close the menu.

https://jsfiddle.net/t6wpgjrd/

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target.id === "dropdownImg") {
      show();
    }
    else{
      hide();
  }
}
```

And don't forget to remove the `onclick` and `onblur` attributes from your `dropdownImg` element.